# Check USB Type-C to Type-C cable resistance with breakout board?

Tags: usb

I have USB Type-C breakout board and wanted to check USB Type-C to Type-C cable resistance, but multimeter shows only "0L".
I can get resistance if I check with USB Type-A to Type-C cable using A5 and VBUS.
I switched multimeter to 6kΩ, 60kΩ and 600kΩ but none worked for C to C cable.
How can I check cable resistance of C to C cable?

Comment: You can probably do it with a very fine wire extended from each of the multimeter probes, connected to specific pins on the inside of the plug.  Test the wire for resistance first, and subtract that from the result.  You'll want to review which pins line up to which; don't forget it's reversible.  Why do you want to know the resistance?

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to test RAVPower's C to C cable because RAVPower said it has 56kΩ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Type-C to Type-C cable is called "full-featured" cable. In Type-C to Type-C cable there is no pullup resistor between CC pin and VBUS, there is a wire-through between two CC pins on both ends of C-C cable.

The basic current supply capability is signaled by pull-up inside the **host port**, and this value is propagated to Type-C device (with 5.1k pull-down) over CC wire (pin A5) to make determination how much current the device can consume.

The pull-up resistors are only in "legacy" cables, where they are built-in Type-C overmold. The reason is simple - legacy Type-A ports don't have the place for CC pin and therefore can't signal their power capability, so the pull-up must go into Type-C overmold, with most conservative value of 56k.